# Loop through a foreach and grab each date item LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have MVC 5 C# web API. I am going to display delivery days calculation according to system date. My code is working for single sub region with post code for the delivery day display (same post code has may sub regions). Can anyone please help me

This is my delivery details screen.

[image]

This is my C# code

```html
int weeklyLogic = 0;
DateTime Firstweek = new DateTime();
DateTime cutDayFirst = new DateTime();

foreach (var delivery in day)
{

 weeklyLogic = ((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), delivery.DeliveryDay) - (int)today.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;
   var nextweeklyLogic = today.AddDays(weeklyLogic);
   Firstweek = nextweeklyLogic;
   var cutDayLogic = nextweeklyLogic.AddDays(-delivery.CloseDayId);
   cutDayFirst = cutDayLogic;                 
 
}

var Location = (from su in db.Suburbs.AsEnumerable()
                                 where su.postcode.Contains(pcode) &&
                                 su.name.Contains(SuburbName)
                                 join sur in db.SubRegions on
                                 su.SubRegionID equals sur.SubregionID
                                 join re in db.AuRegions on
                                 sur.RegionID equals re.RegionID
                                 join DT in db.DeliveryPeriods on
                                 sur.DeliveryTimeId equals DT.Id
                                 select new Posts
                                 {
                                     suburb = new Suburb()

                                     {
                                         name = su.name,
                                         postcode = su.postcode,
                                       
                                     },
                                     region = new Region()
                                     {
                                         Name = re.Name
                                     },

                                     deliveryTime = new DeliveryTime()
                                     {

                                         DeliveryDay = DT.DeliveryDay,
                                         DeliveryType = DT.DeliveryType,

                                     },

                                     subRegion = new SubRegion()
                                     {
                                         CloseDayId = sur.CloseDayId,
                                         SubregionName = sur.SubregionName,
                                         SubregionID = sur.SubregionID
                                     },
                                     deliveryDays = new DeliveryDays() 
                                     {
                                       
                                        Firstweek = Firstweek,
                                        cutDayFirst = cutDayFirst,
                                     },
                                   }).ToList();
                return Location1.Select(l => new LocationDTO

                {
                    DeliveryDay = l.deliveryTime.DeliveryDay,
                    PostCode = l.suburb.postcode,
                    CloseDayId = l.subRegion.CloseDayId,
                    SubregionID = l.subRegion.SubregionID,
                    TFirstDeliveryDay = l.deliveryDays.Firstweek.ToString("dddd, d MMMM yyyy"),
                    TFirstCutOffDay = l.deliveryDays.cutDayFirst.ToString("dddd, d MMMM yyyy"),
          
                }).ToList();
```

This is my out put, I marked errors. 
[image]

Comment: you are using the day of week logic in that piece of code.

Comment: yes, your are correct

Comment: can you please elaborate what issue you are facing.

Comment: @Rob so don't use it and I guess you will get the complete date

Comment: The loop will display all  CloseDayId low value id. Example close day Id 1

Comment: The loop will display all  CloseDayId low value id with list, pls refer my out put screen.

Comment: @Arijit my code Firstweek = nextweeklyLogic date is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can see your logic is incorrect by foreach loop.
as per your for each

```
     int weeklyLogic = 0;
     DateTime Firstweek = new DateTime();
     DateTime cutDayFirst = new DateTime();

    foreach (var delivery in day)
    {

      weeklyLogic = ((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), delivery.DeliveryDay) - (int)today.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;
      var nextweeklyLogic = today.AddDays(weeklyLogic);
      //initiated for all further processing by last value of day 
      Firstweek = nextweeklyLogic;
     //initiated for all further processing by last value of day

      var cutDayLogic = nextweeklyLogic.AddDays(-delivery.CloseDayId);
      cutDayFirst = cutDayLogic;                 

    }
```

by above logic Firstweek ,cutDayFirst  always be the last one set by the foreach loop and these value will be same for all the Location .

your entire location logic should be inside foreach.

**Update**

create a new class

```
public class calculatedDays
{

    public int SubRegionID{ get; set; }
    public DateTime Firstweekdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime cutDayFirstdate { get; set; }
}
```

and by your for each logic do this.

```
    int weeklyLogic = 0;
    DateTime Firstweek = new DateTime();
    DateTime cutDayFirst = new DateTime();
    List<calculatedDays>Days=new List<calculatedDays>();
   foreach (var delivery in day)
   {

   weeklyLogic = ((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), delivery.DeliveryDay) - (int)today.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;
     var nextweeklyLogic = today.AddDays(weeklyLogic);
     Firstweek = nextweeklyLogic;
    var cutDayLogic = nextweeklyLogic.AddDays(-delivery.CloseDayId);
    cutDayFirst = cutDayLogic;        


    calculatedDays d= new calculatedDays();
    d.SubRegionID=delivery.SubRegionID;
    d.Firstweekdate =Firstweek ;
    d.cutDayFirstdate =cutDayFirst ;
    Days.add(d);
  }
```

for your location calculation add these changes.

```
    var Location = (from su in db.Suburbs.AsEnumerable()
                             where su.postcode.Contains(pcode) &&
                             su.name.Contains(SuburbName)
                             join sur in db.SubRegions on
                             su.SubRegionID equals sur.SubregionID
                             join re in db.AuRegions on
                             sur.RegionID equals re.RegionID
                             join DT in db.DeliveryPeriods on
                             sur.DeliveryTimeId equals DT.Id
                             join dts in Days on
                             su.SubRegionID equals dts.SubRegionID 
                             select new Posts
                             {
                                 suburb = new Suburb()

                                 {
                                     name = su.name,
                                     postcode = su.postcode,

                                 },
                                 region = new Region()
                                 {
                                     Name = re.Name
                                 },

                                 deliveryTime = new DeliveryTime()
                                 {

                                     DeliveryDay = DT.DeliveryDay,
                                     DeliveryType = DT.DeliveryType,

                                 },

                                 subRegion = new SubRegion()
                                 {
                                     CloseDayId = sur.CloseDayId,
                                     SubregionName = sur.SubregionName,
                                     SubregionID = sur.SubregionID
                                 },
                                 deliveryDays = new DeliveryDays() 
                                 {

                                    Firstweek = dts.Firstweekdate ,
                                    cutDayFirst = dts.cutDayFirstdate,
                                 },
                               }).ToList();
            return Location1.Select(l => new LocationDTO

            {
                DeliveryDay = l.deliveryTime.DeliveryDay,
                PostCode = l.suburb.postcode,
                CloseDayId = l.subRegion.CloseDayId,
                SubregionID = l.subRegion.SubregionID,
                TFirstDeliveryDay = l.deliveryDays.Firstweek.ToString("dddd, d MMMM yyyy"),
                TFirstCutOffDay = l.deliveryDays.cutDayFirst.ToString("dddd, d MMMM yyyy"),

            }).ToList();
```

Hope it will help you . thanks. :)

Comment: either your location logic or your date calculation should be inside linq . then it will we working proper. :)

Comment: if add entire location logic  inside foreach it will come. Error 1ValuesController.Get(string, string)': not all code paths return a value

Comment: Also my  return Location1.Select(l => new LocationDTO middle of the loop. How do I add location inside foreach?

Comment: don't add location inside foreach , add the logic of foreach in your linq of location.

Comment: is that date calculation is unique with SubRegionID ?

Comment: Ok then let me update the answer for resolving the issue.

Comment: I am testing now, all working I found small issue, final out put return XML, duplicated list will come. Thank you for your help. Well done

Comment: Hello @Viplock,  If SubRegionID has same number two or more, why is repeating? example Id has 4 twice, it'll repeat twice.

Comment: use Days.Distinct() at the time of joining it in last query.